# How does iOS get the background to seemingly change brightness over time?

Tags: html, css, image, filter

I've noticed that my background on my MacBook Air seems to adjust to the time outside, growing darker as it gets darker.

Can I emulate this effect using CSS on my website.

What parameter are they varying and can I use a css filter to do similar?

[image: my site background]

[image: macOS background]

Answer (score 1):

It's not a parameter or filter, but multiple actual photographs.

https://www.idownloadblog.com/2018/06/06/macos-mojave-dynamic-wallpaper-desktop/

> Apple took multiple photographs of the same spot at various intervals between sunrise and dusk to achieve the incredibly smooth transition between day and night. Thanks to enthusiasts, we know that Mojave’s dynamic wallpaper includes 16 layers in one HEIC file.

You can do the same yourself - just show a different background image at different times of day.

Answer (score 0):

You can add images on top of a black background and depending on the time change the image's opacity.